# JSON data extraction to variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a problem to deal with the JSON array, I have a name which gives me the code formatted to the code below.

```
nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries
    (11) [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a]
    0:a {id: 2, articleId: "1156688772", type: 2, html: "<div id="DIV_1" style="box-sizing:border-box;color…ionUI.enableUserInput()    }</script></div></div>", text: "Fyll ut feltene under for å starte en chat: Alle f…tionSession.conversationUI.enableUserInput()    }"}
    1:a {id: 3, type: 5, date: 1529495789458, html: "", text: ""}
    2:a {id: 4, type: 1, html: "jeg har fått ny adresse", text: "jeg har fått ny adresse"}
    3:a {id: 5, articleId: "1155556302", type: 2, html: "<p style="margin-bottom: 0.11in;"><span style="lin…ilte-sporsmal/min-side/</a></u></font></span></p>", text: "Du kan endre personlige opplysninger på Min Side. …rivat/kundeservice/ofte-stilte-sporsmal/min-side/"}
    4:a {id: 6, type: 5, date: 1529562815900, html: "", text: ""}
    5:a {id: 7, type: 1, html: "bestille brikke", text: "bestille brikke"}
    6:a {id: 8, articleId: "1137471592", type: 2, html: "<p>Du kan bestille brikkefeste her:<br /><br /><a …html" target="_blank">Bestill brikkefeste</a></p>", text: "Du kan bestille brikkefeste her:Bestill brikkefeste"}
    7:a {id: 9, type: 1, html: "hvordan betaler", text: "hvordan betaler"}
    8:a {id: 10, articleId: "1155921422", type: 2, html: "<p>Hvis du betaler fra en utenlandsk konto, m&arin…erer hvilke fakturanummer betalingen gjelder.</p>", text: "Hvis du betaler fra en utenlandsk konto, må du bru…ifiserer hvilke fakturanummer betalingen gjelder."}
    9:a {id: 11, type: 1, html: "hvor kan jeg bruke brikken fra fjellinjen", text: "hvor kan jeg bruke brikken fra fjellinjen"}
    10:a {id: 12, articleId: "1140979222", type: 2, html: "Du kan bruke bombrikken i alle autopassanlegg i hele Skandinavia", text: "Du kan bruke bombrikken i alle autopassanlegg i hele Skandinavia"}
    length
    :11
    __proto__
    :Array(0)
```

I would like to know is anyone have an idea how to extract the nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries[2].text all until nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries[12].text.
Also there is one more problem because the lentgh of array would not always be the same. sometimes it will be 10, sometimes 2 data blocks written. I would like to make a variable which will contain all the data from nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries[all the length].text, in plain text with space between them.

I was trying to something like this. But since I'm in the Intermidiate level with Javascript and JSON. Anyway here's my code, and any help or corerction would be appreciated.

```
var i=2;
  var history = nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries.length;
    while (i<history) {
      printObject (nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries[i].text);
}
```

Okay I managed to solve the problem somehow, Thank you [**Nina Scholz**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) you beautiful named lady for the solution.

I just have another problem, the converting dots to new lines (linebreaks).
I converted string using:

```
chatHistory2 = historyText.toString();
```

Also result was looking like this:

```
jeg vil si opp avtalen min med fjellinjen hvordan gjør det,Husk å ta brikken ut av bilen. Videre må du si opp avtalen din på Min side. Brikken kan du bruke om igjen, eller kaste i miljøavfall hvis du ikke ønsker å gjenbruke den.,hvordan får jeg tilbake depositumet på bombrikken,Du får tilbake depositumet når avtalen din avsluttes. Du kan avslutte avtalen på Min side. Depositumet på 200kr blir da enten trukket fra eventuelt utestående på avtalen, eller så blir tilbakebetalt til kontoen din. Når avtalen er avsluttet kan brikken kastes som elektrisk avfall.
```

Ok. there is my problem, I tried to use:

```
chatHistory = chatHistory2.replace(/./gi, /<br>/); and

chatHistory = chatHistory2.replace(/./gi, /\n/);
```

but without success. What am I doing wrong in this case? How to make on every dot, to result goes in new line?

Comment: you do not have index 12 in the array.

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop? `for (var i = 0; i < nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries.length; i++) { console.log(nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries[i].text); }`

Comment: I mention 12 because that number in array is changeable, maybe i did not explained it well, I know that currently there is no 12. data in array, but is there a way to make it '.slice (2, number of array length at the time)' ?
Actually your solution get's me right next to the solution, but instead of console.log I vould like to create a new variable to collect the sliced data. @Nina Scholz I actually wanted to comment you on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice the wanted range and iterate this array.

- [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for getting parts of the array,
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating an array,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for taking variables as values of properties.

---

```
var array = nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries;

array
    .slice(2, 12)
    .forEach(({ text }) => {
        console.log(text);
    });
```

For assigning the wanted property, you could map `text`.

```
var array = nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries,
    chatHistory = array.slice(2, 12).map(({ text }) => text);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it instead of console.log(text), to make it a new variable named chatHistory. That i would like to use as a way to collect data from it and pass it to the other HTML element.

Comment: is `chatHistory` an array?

Comment: I think it is, yes, for me it looks like a array

Comment: The code you jus gave me gives me perfect result, just what i wanted, but I neet to collect it to binding, let me call it like dat maybe variable is too conected to var, to show it in the another div.

Comment: i have no idea, what you are asking.

Comment: And i gave you wrong information sorry, {chatHistory} is a example of binding name in which I want to collect result of your {.slice and foreach} solution.
It's early mornig here and I'm struggling with this all night trying to find a way to work. so i'm little confusing with the comments, sorry for that.

Comment: where do you get `code` from? what do you mean by *binding*? maybe you take a nap and return later.

Comment: I got it from the website [Test site I'm working on](http://52.59.231.55/), but when you engage chat bot somehow, after you type in console `nanorep.floatingWidget.$refs.core.conversationSession.entries` you get the array.
Now I want to collect results from that array to plain text and to display it in the agents field. The way to do that is to create result that your solution above creates and collect it in a variable or binding, whatever you like to call it and to pull it in the another html element of the internal system that support agents are using to help the people chatting.